# Scrollable container within flex layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm currently working on a simple CSS layout consisting of two panes, which sit side by side, and a footer.  I have the following restrictions:

- The left-hand pane is fixed width.
- The footer is fixed height and
  must not fall of the bottom of the containing div.
- The remaining dimensions expand to fill the available space.
- The right-hand pane contains a lot of content.  It should wrap horizontally and scroll vertically.

I have attempted to produce something suitable using flexbox.  [A working example can be found on jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Merryweather/c0b2vku5/4/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="left">
       Top-left content
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="rightInternal">
        Large content goes here.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    Bottom pane content should not collapse or be pushed outside the bounds of 'container'.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.left {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 30%;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.rightInternal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom {
  padding: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

The problem:

This works fine in Chrome but the content in 'top' grows outside the bounds of 'container' in IE and FF due to the large content.  Setting a height on the content of 'top' either results in the footer being pushed off the bottom (height: 100%) or the content not expanding to fill the available vertical space (height: 100px, for example).

How can I create my desired layout?

Notes:

- The JSFiddle example has been modified slightly to make container size nicely and to make everything colorful so it can be easily identified.  In my actual environment, height 100% will make the container fill the visible space that it sits within, which is as desired.
- There is no requirement for me to use flexbox.

Comment: Setting `min-height: 0` on `top` will fix this  issue, and the dupe link explains it

Comment: @LGSon thank you!  `min-height: 0` does indeed fix it in FF, but not in IE.  The explanation in the dupe link lead me to discover that `flex-basis:0px` fixed IE (but not FF).  I'll use both.  Thanks again.

Comment: Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Merryweather/c0b2vku5/5/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the layout you want using by adding `overflow` property to `.top`

Set `overflow` to `hidden`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5cp0d26d/1/)

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgba(255, 125, 125, 1);
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(238, 130, 238, 1);
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 30%;
  background: rgba(135, 206, 250, 1);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.right {
  background: rgba(152, 251, 152, 1);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.rightInternal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 153, 1);
  padding: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="left">
      Top-left content
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="rightInternal">
        This rainbow should scroll!
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div style="background-color:red;height:60px">Richard</div>
        <div style="background-color:orange;height:60px">of</div>
        <div style="background-color:yellow;height:60px">York</div>
        <div style="background-color:green;height:60px">gained</div>
        <div style="background-color:blue;height:60px">battle</div>
        <div style="background-color:indigo;height:60px">in</div>
        <div style="background-color:violet;min-height:60px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris in congue ipsum. Suspendisse maximus non magna sed blandit. Fusce mattis nisl elit, a sollicitudin justo porta ac. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices
          posuere cubilia Curae; Donec elementum nunc ac vehicula dictum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla ultricies ipsum dignissim quam venenatis, in vehicula eros ultrices. Maecenas ut malesuada
          nulla.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    Bottom pane content should not collapse or be pushed outside the bounds of 'container'.
  </div>
</div>
```